# javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Named query not found: findAll

Tags: hibernate, jpa, named-query

I've tried to create simple JPA aplication using MySql and Hibernate, I want load 4 records from table student 
[db table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gbuq9.png)

but i recieve this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Named query not found: findAll
```

Here is my Entity Class

```
package entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="student")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "findAll", query = "select st from student st")
    })
public class student{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="surname")
    private String surname;

    @Column(name="sex")
    private String sex;

    public student(String name, String surname, String sex) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    public void setSex(String sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "student [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", surname=" + surname + ", sex=" + sex + "]";

}
```

DAO

```
package dao;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import entity.student;

public class StudentDAO {

    public List<student> getAllStd(EntityManager em){
        TypedQuery<student> q = em.createNamedQuery("findAll", student.class);
        return q.getResultList();       
    }       
}
```

and finally bean that calls the DAO method

```
package test;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import dao.StudentDAO;
import entity.student;

@Stateless
public class Test2Bean {

    @PersistenceContext()
    private EntityManager em;       

     public void getAllStudents(){
         StudentDAO stdDAO = new StudentDAO();
         List<student> students = stdDAO.getAllStd(em);
         System.out.println(students.size());
     }      
}
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
 <persistence-unit name="mysql">
 <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
 <jta-data-source>java:jboss/mysqlds</jta-data-source>
 <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
 <properties>

 <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
 <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
 <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true" />
 <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
</properties>

</persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

i have no idea why DAO method cant access query, i made few test methods in entity class and DAO method has access to Entity Student.

- I added whole error message http://pastebin.com/agBxHg7K

Thanks for all answers

Comment: have you tried putting the class in persistence.xml ? because then it is known about and hence any NamedQuery should be loaded ...

Comment: I don't see a no-arg constructor on your `student` entity. Do you have one in there?

Answer (score 1):

Try...

```
@Entity
@Table(name="student")
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Student.findAll", query = "select st from student st")
})
public class student{
```

Add Student. before "findAll"

not sure if that's it but my named queries normally have that.

Comment: yeah i know this trick, all queries have to contain unique name, i just want keep this test code simple, but im aware of this, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Probably if you mark StudentDAO as @Stateless does solve it, because of the context where is used the entity manager.
Also is possible to work if you use the entity manager in Test2Bean .